# How to add count of pending tasks to List Json

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am creating a todo list API(backend) in django rest framework. I have two models List and Task

```
#models.py

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class List(models.Model):
    list_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.list_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'list'


class Task(models.Model):
    todo_list = models.ForeignKey(List, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    due_date = models.DateField()
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'task'
```

The serializers file,

```
#serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework_serializer_extensions.serializers import SerializerExtensionsMixin
from .models import List, Task


class ListSerializer(SerializerExtensionsMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = List
        fields = "__all__"

class TaskSerializer(SerializerExtensionsMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = "__all__"
        expandable_fields = dict(
            todolist=ListSerializer
        )
```

My todo list app will have multiple lists and each list have multiple tasks. Each task will have a due date and can be marked as done. I am trying to add the number of pending tasks to my List json. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new field using [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
class ListSerializer(SerializerExtensionsMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pending_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = List
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_pending_count(self, obj):
       return obj.task_set.filter(done=False).count()
```